# Negative electric polarization on dielectric material

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization, dielectric

I've been solving the first problem set in my E&M course, and have come across something I *think* is unphysical.

The problem consists of a parallel plate capacitor in which an inhomogeneous dielectric is placed within, with an electric permittivity given by

$$\varepsilon=\varepsilon_p e^{-\beta y},$$

Where $\varepsilon_p$ and $\beta$ are positive constants, and $y$ is parallel to the plates.

The problem I have with that, is if we take 
$$y>\frac{1}{\beta}\log\frac{\varepsilon_p}{\varepsilon_0},$$

We get $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$. This would directly imply that the polarization of the dielectric is directly against the electric field. How does this make sense? I know it is possible when we have electromagnetic waves and possible phase lag between waves and polarization, but I can't even conceive of an *electrostatic* system with this property.

Comment: @veereshpandey as I mentioned, the $y$ axis is parallel to the surface, and the plates are in the planes $x=0$ and $x=L$.

Comment: The relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_p$ cannot be true for all $y$.

Comment: @jim that's what I thought, but the problem does not specify any other dependence

Comment: It might be best to take this up with the person who set the question? Or was it from a text book, if so what was the title?

Comment: @jim the problem set was probably written by the professor, I'll chech up with him later this week